# Salesforce Single Sign On with Delegated Authentication using Google App Engine

Tags: single-sign-on, google-apps, delegated-authentication, subversion

I am trying to do delegated authentication using google app engine  I am getting multiple issues. First of all tortoize svn tells me that the svn checkout in this page https://code.google.com/p/sfdc-gae-sso-delegated-auth/source/checkout  is not found. Now when I am trying to install google  app engine plugin in ecilpse GALELIO resource not found error is coming how to proceed now. I am fine with identity provider other than  google also.

Comment: Why Delegated Authentication? You can do [OpenId Connect from Google to Salesforce](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/09/login-to-your-salesforce-org-with-openid-connect-in-winter-14.html), or [SAML from Salesforce to Google](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Configuring-SAML-SSO-to-GoogleApps).